# Another "Cannot make static reference..." Question

Tags: android, static

I am trying to write an Activity that has some views, a fillView() method that sets the views (which is not static because it must utilize getContentResolver), and a static method that makes a random choice from a cursor and then runs the fillView() method.

I had problems with this due to fillView not being static and pickRandom being static, so I tried to initialzize an instance of the class, but now it crashes on the line instance.fillView();

Sample code below.   Any help would be appreciated.  Perhaps there is a much easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Thanks,
Josh

```
public class myView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


@Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.myView);

fillView();

    }


public void fillView(){

    //creates views, runs cursor and applies results to the view created

}

public static void pickRandom() {   


          // runs cursor, picks random entry, next I want to apply the result to 
          //  view, so I run...

        myView v = new myView();
        v.fillView();

        }
```

Comment: is `getContentResolver()` static?, I don't see any static methods here.

Comment: pickRandom() is static, and will not allow me to use fillView() within.

Comment: hence my addition of the 'myView v' instance, but this causes a crash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a static instance variable and set in in oncreate:

```
private static myView instance;
```

oncreate()

```
instance = this;
```

static pickrandom()

```
instance.fillView();
```

Comment: Still crashing on the instance.fillView(); bit.

Comment: Caught another part that was causing the error and this works fine now.

Comment: Thanks for the great help!  StackOverlfow comes through again.

Answer (score 0):

in your pickRandom you try to create new instance of your class. Instead of this you should do the following:

```
this.fillView();
```

I don't see any purpose you have your pickRandom static.

If, however, you need it for some reason you can pass a reference to your view like this:

```
public static void pickRandom(myView v) {   


  // runs cursor, picks random entry, next I want to apply the result to 
  //  view, so I run...

  v.fillView();

}
```

Comment: This is difficult because I utilize the pickRandom method in other activities, and don't always have the views available to pass.  If I try this.fillView(); it tells me "Cannot use this in a static context"