# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method invalidate() from the type View MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, methods, static

I'm getting an error in eclipse stating: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method invalidate() from the type View   MainActivity.java" and I'm not sure exactly what I can do to resolve this. How can I either make invalidate() static or make View non-static?

SOURCE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
           // perform HTTP client operation
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String title) {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(title);
                        View.invalidate();
                    }
            });
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.google.com" });

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readWebpage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Load Webpage" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Placeholder" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

FIRST SOLUTION ATTEMPT:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;
   // String response;
    public interface Callback {
        void onModifiedTextView(String value);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    }

    public void onModifiedTextView(final String title) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(title);
                textView.invalidate(); // not even necessary
            }
        });
    }

    public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public DownloadWebPageTask(MainActivity mainActivity) {
            this.callback = mainActivity;
        }

        private MainActivity callback;

        public DownloadWebPageTask() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public DownloadWebPageTask(TextView textView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";

            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                     Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com")
                                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                                .get();
                    // get page title
                    String title = doc.title();
                    System.out.println("title : " + title);

                    // get all links
                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                    for (Element link : links) {

                        // get the value from href attribute
                        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
                        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            callback.onModifiedTextView(response);
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String title) {
            callback.onModifiedTextView(title);
        }  
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask(this);
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.google.com" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `DownloadWebPageTask` in the `doInBackground` method of `DownloadWebPageTask`? You should be creating it in the `onClick` method by passing `this`, which is a `Callback`. Make your `MainActivity` implement `Callback`.

Comment: I updated my source above - does everything look correct to you?

Comment: Yes it seems fine, but the `interface Callback` is very useless, you aren't using it, you're using `MainActivity` directly. It should work, but you are going to very high coupling between your classes. Something to consider avoiding in the future (or once it works).

Comment: No errors at this point... but The textview still does not display the  data from the title tag off google.com

Comment: Can you check that the `onModifiedTextView` is actually called? If it is, I would think there is something wrong with the `TextView`.

Comment: I set a breakpoint at -  public void onModifiedTextView(String title) { and it is never called.

Comment: That should mean that `onPostExecute` is never called. Try putting the line `callback.onModifiedTextView(title);` before `return response` in 
`doInBackground` method.

Comment: I did - it results in: title cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: I'm defining it as String title; and testing it now

Comment: Use `response` instead of `title`. They should be the same.

Comment: I just tried it (updated source above) and ended up with a force close error

Comment: Actually check and do the same as I do in the `onModifiedTextView` method in my edit to my answer. The update to UI elements needs to happen on the UI thread.

Comment: I updated my source above with your suggestion - it results in:
Cannot refer to a non-final variable title inside an inner class defined in a different method on the line:    textView.setText(title);

Comment: Oh god, I keep forgetting stuff. Just make `title` a `final` variable. `final String title`.

Comment: Ok - I did - no errors: it simply does not update the textview

Comment: Is the `TestView` even visible on the main view?

Comment: Yes - when I first launch the application it has the text placeholder then once the "load webpage" button is clicked it disappears (instead of being updated with the new data)

Comment: Any other suggestions? (it's still not working)

Comment: Try setting the textView visibility `setVisibility(VISIBLE)`

Comment: No, call that method on the `textView`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Comment: textView.setVisibility(VISIBLE); results in "VISIBLE cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: I understand you're new to this, but you have to help yourself. `VISIBLE` is a constant from the `View` class, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE)

Comment: Ok. Should:   public void onClick(View view) {
     textview.setVisibility(VISIBLE); work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`View` is a class. `invalidate()` is an instance method. You need to call it on an instance.

However, [you need to perform UI modifications on the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread). I would make your `Activity` class implement a `Callback` interface with a method like

```
public interface Callback {
    void onModifiedTextView(String value);
}
```

Your class then implements it as

```
public void onModifiedTextView(final String title) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(title);
            textView.invalidate(); // not even necessary
        }
    });
}
```

Then pass that to `DownloadWebPageTask`. In other words, create a constructor that accepts a `Callback` instance

```
public DownloadWebPageTask(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

private Callback callback;

...

protected void onPostExecute(final String title) {
    callback.onModifiedTextView(title);
}
```

UI modifications need to be done of the UI thread. That's why you need the `runOnUiThread()` method.

Comment: It's actually a suggestion from another issue I'm having... this might shed a bit more light on the situation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728984/cannot-parse-html-data-using-android-jsoup

Comment: @OverflowCustodian That suggestion is bad and mine is just as bad. Create a callback so that the activity calls the invalidate() on the `TextView`, not the `DownloadWebPageTask`.

Comment: Thanks! I attempted to implement it (I updated my source above) but i'm getting an NPE on the line: callback.onModifiedTextView(title);

Comment: @OverflowCustodian You forgot to pass the Activity instance in your constructor, `DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask(this);` otherwise the `callback` field is initialized to `null`. Get rid of your no-args constructor.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure exactly what you mean by get rid my no-args constructor

Comment: @OverflowCustodian You have a `DownloadWebPageTask` constructor that doesn't have any parameters. Remove it, you don't need it. This way you also can't confuse which constructor to use as there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Java tutorial on **Instance and Class Methods**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), where this is explained thoroughly.

Also, see [Another "Cannot make static reference..." Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266484/another-cannot-make-static-reference-question), [Java Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744746/java-error-cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method).

Answer (score 0):

invalidate() is a non static method in the VIEW class. you need to invoke that method after creating any instance of View or any of its child . In this case you can try invalidating the textView  or  root view of your activity.